# ExpressionEngine Crop and Resize, keep proportions

Tags: codeigniter, expressionengine

I am currently developing a site in ExpressionEngine which allows users to upload photos for articles and a slideshow. I have tried both of the inbuilt resizing and cropping features that EE provides but none of them do what I need.

I have an area of 620px X 200px which needs to be filled with the uploaded image. The image can be resized and cropped as much as needed aslong as the proportions stay constrained and the end result fills the 620x200 area.

Is there any way for me to do this within EE or will I have to find some sort of module/plugin to do this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not experienced in doing this in vanilla EE code, but only because I throw down $15 on every site I make to purchase the [CE Image](http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-image/user-guide/) plugin. It has incredible support for this and many, many other image manipulations. If you're not opposed to spending a few coins, give it a whirl! You won't be disappointed.

If you *are*, however, looking for free options, I would mess around with EE's native [Image manipulations](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/cp/content/files/file_upload_preferences.html#image-manipulations). Again, I must say that I've never used this option because of my preference for CE Image, but it's free and may do exactly what you want it to do. Either way, best of luck!

Comment: I second the recommendation for CE Image - it's brilliant. If you really can't stretch to $15, then try [ED Imageresier](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ed-imageresizer)